# Sklearn PCA function - unhashable type: 'slice'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pca

my code's major objective is transform a 3D dataframe to 2D by PCA decomposition , but unable to executed it, i assume the question is the return , but dont know how to correct it , please review:

```
def do_PCA(x, svd_solver):

   from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
   pca = PCA(n_components=2, svd_solver='full')
   pca.fit(x)                 
   PCA(copy=True, iterated_power='auto', n_components=2, random_state=None, 
   svd_solver='full', tol=0.0, whiten=False)
   return x

pca = do_PCA(x, "full")

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('Full PCA')
ax.scatter(pca[:,0], pca[:,1], c='blue', marker='.', alpha=0.75)
plt.show()
```

The error I get:

```
TypeError    Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-66-94cd1f5059d5> in <module>()
  3 ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
  4 ax.set_title('Full PCA')
  -> 5 ax.scatter(pca[:,0], pca[:,1], c='blue', marker='.', alpha=0.75)
  6 plt.show()

  TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Comment: The code you added is not correct. The data returned from function do_pca() is same as that was sent.

Comment: may i ask what shoud be the return @VivekKumar

Comment: It should return the transformed x, which would be the principle components. Also, not sure why you're wrapping the PCA process in a custom function with a `svd_solver` argument when it will always be "full' regardless of what you pass into your custom function.

Comment: sorry i am not sure how to return the transformed x,is it "pca.fit(x)" , however this is an excerse, to leave the svd_solver because we will test "random" after "full" @Scratch'N'Purr

Comment: @PepinPeng, what @Scratch'N'Purr is trying to say is that after you do `.fit(x)`, you need to do `.transform(x)`.

Comment: pca = PCA(n_components=2).fit(x)
pca_2d = pca.transform(x)
return pca_2d

Comment: instead of `return x` try `return  pca.transform(x)`

Comment: thanks !! that works for me ! @Flika205

Comment: it works out, thanks !@Dan